# Prove arbitrarily-nested Vect alias is showable

Tags: type-inference, idris, dependent-type

I've been trying to figure out how to implement `Show` for my `Tensor` type for ages. `Tensor` is a thin wrapper round either a single value, or arbitrarily-nested `Vect`s of values

```
import Data.Vect

Shape : Nat -> Type
Shape rank = Vect rank Nat

array_type: (shape: Shape rank) -> (dtype: Type) -> Type
array_type [] dtype = dtype
array_type (d :: ds) dtype = Vect d (array_type ds dtype)

data Tensor : (shape: Shape rank) -> (dtype: Type) -> Type where
  MkTensor : array_type shape dtype -> Tensor shape dtype

Show dtype => Show (Tensor shape dtype) where
  show (MkTensor x) = show x
```

I get

```
When checking right hand side of Prelude.Show.Main.Tensor shape dtype implementation of Prelude.Show.Show, method show with expected type
        String

Can't find implementation for Show (array_type shape dtype)
```

which is understandable given `array_type`'s not trivial. I believe that it should be `show`able, as I can `show` highly-nested `Vect`s in the REPL as long their elements are `Show`. I guess Idris just doesn't know it's an arbitrarily nested `Vect`.

If I pull in some implicit parameters and case split on rank/shape, I get somewhere

```
Show dtype => Show (Tensor {rank} shape dtype) where
  show {rank = Z} {shape = []} (MkTensor x) = show x  -- works
  show {rank = (S Z)} {shape = (d :: [])} (MkTensor x) = show x  -- works
  show {rank = (S k)} {shape = (d :: ds)} (MkTensor x) = show x  -- doesn't work
```

and I can indefinitely expand this to higher and higher rank *explicitly*, where the RHS is always just `show x`, but I can't figure out how to get this to type check for all ranks. I'd guess some recursive thing is required.

**EDIT** to be clear, I want to know how to do this by using Idris' implementation of `Show` for `Vect`s. I want to avoid having to construct an implementation manually myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go via the `Show (Vect n a)` implementations, you can do that as well, by defining a `Show` implementation that requires that there is a `Show` for the vector:

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.List

Shape : Nat -> Type
Shape rank = Vect rank Nat

array_type: (shape: Shape rank) -> (dtype: Type) -> Type
array_type [] dtype = dtype
array_type (d :: ds) dtype = Vect d (array_type ds dtype)

data Tensor : (shape: Shape rank) -> (dtype: Type) -> Type where
  MkTensor : array_type shape dtype -> Tensor shape dtype

Show (array_type shape dtype) => Show (Tensor {rank} shape dtype) where
  show (MkTensor x) = show x
```

For all choices of `shape`, the `Show (array_type shape dtype)` constraint will reduce to `Show dtype`, so e.g. this works:

```
myTensor : Tensor [1, 2, 3] Int
myTensor = MkTensor [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

```
*ShowVect> show myTensor 
"[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]" : String
```

Comment: ah, nice. I hoped it was something simple. I didn't realise you can constrain on a type-level function, since I think Brady's book says it's not allowed to _implement_ interfaces for type-level functions. here's 175 rep

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track: you can do it by writing a recursive function over the nested vectors, and then lifting it to your `Tensor` type in the `Show` implementation:

```
showV : Show dtype => array_type shape dtype -> String
showV {rank = 0} {shape = []} x = show x
showV {rank = (S k)} {shape = d :: ds} xs = combine $ map showV xs
  where
    combine : Vect n String -> String
    combine ss = "[" ++ concat (intersperse ", " . toList $ ss) ++ "]"

Show dtype => Show (Tensor {rank} shape dtype) where
  show (MkTensor x) = showV x
```

Example:

```
λΠ> show $ the (Tensor [1, 2, 3] Int) $ MkTensor [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
"[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm more wondering if I can take advantage of the fact that idris already defines `Show` for arbitrarily nested `Vect`s